# How to return a pointer from a function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have a struct called `playerInformation` that I want to return from a function within my C program, the below function is the one that I've written.

It finds the right struct and I can use `printf` to print the details within the function. However it seems that I can't return a pointer so that I can print the information within the main function.

With this code I get this warning:

```
MainTest.c: In function ‘main’:
MainTest.c:34: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

MainTest.c (line 33 and 34)

```
struct playerInformation *test;
test = findPlayerInformation(head, 2);
```

StructFucntions.c

```
struct playerInformation *findPlayerInformation(struct playerInformation *head, int playerIndex) {
    struct playerInformation *ptr;
        for(ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
            if(ptr->playerIndex == playerIndex) {
                return ptr;
            }
        }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: is `findPlayerInformation` declared (put in a header file, included in maintest.c before `main` definition) ?

Comment: put prototype before use.

Comment: actually it's "just" a warning .. is findPlayerInformation located below your main function or have you defined the function prototype before ?

Comment: purplepsycho was right, coming from a java background i completely omitted adding the new function to my header file, apologies for the dumb question!

Comment: Configure your compiler correctly. GCC older than version 5 is per default set to be a bad compiler (gnu90). Instead use `gcc std=c11 -pedantic-errors` and it would have told you exactly what was the problem (missing function prototype).

Answer (score 1):

[Put prototype before use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863500/how-to-return-a-pointer-from-a-function-in-c/39242592#comment61294294_36863500) — [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy)

Once upon a time, the topic "calling a function from another C file" in SO documentation covered the issue.

In this context, you need a header defining the type `struct playerInformation`:

**`playerinfo.h`**

```
#ifndef PLAYERINFO_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAYERINFO_H_INCLUDED

struct playerInformation
{
    ...
};

extern struct playerInformation *findPlayerInformation(struct playerInformation *head, int playerIndex);

#endif
```

The code in `structFunctions.c` should include the header:

```
#include "playerinfo.h"

...

struct playerInformation *findPlayerInformation(struct playerInformation *head, int playerIndex) {
    struct playerInformation *ptr;
        for(ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
            if(ptr->playerIndex == playerIndex) {
                return ptr;
            }
        }
    return NULL;
}
```

And the main program would include the header too:

**`MainTest.c`**

```
#include "playerinfo.h"

...

int main(void)
{
    struct playerInformation *head = ...;
    ...
    struct playerInformation *test;
    test = findPlayerInformation(head, 2);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You have declared `struct playerInformation *ptr;`, this pointer as a local variable inside `findPlayerInformation()` function... So the scope of the above pointer will be available within `findPlayerInformation()` function only.

```
if(ptr->playerIndex == playerIndex) 
     return ptr;
```

So after this statement, control will go to the main function. Since you declared `ptr` as a local variable inside `findPlayerInformation()` function,  you won't get the `ptr` what you expected in main function..

Solution:

If you want to avoid this problem , declare the ptr as a static variable like below

```
static struct playerInformation *ptr;
```

static keyword used to keep scope of variable in entire file...

Comment: I think you are confusing this for altering a pointer passed as parameter. The code posted is fine and there is no need for static. Also, this wouldn't explain the given compiler warning.

Comment: sorry . just now i have seen that function call & function definition are in different source files .. so you can pass the address of struct pointer as a another parameter to  findPlayerInformation() function & Inside that function , you can fill this address..

Comment: " so you can pass the address of struct pointer as a another parameter" That's what he is doing. It does not matter in which files the function call and function definition are placed.

Comment: Actually in my previous comment , I have mentioned to use " static variable declaration" .. so , if you want to use static declaration then function call & definition should be placed in same file .. For that only i have mentioned about source file.. & "That's what he is doing" , i cant able to find , where he is passing the address of the destination to the 
findPlayerInformation()?????
findPlayerInformation(head, 2) 
he is just passing  head of the linked list & one criteria to find the necessary structure.....

Comment: _i cant able to find , where he is passing the address of the destination_ - He needn't pass the address of the destination, since he is returning a pointer by value, and since the lifetime of the non-local object pointed to does not end at return from function, this is valid.

Comment: @sivakarthik - think of it this way to avoid confusion *A function may always return its own type*. Where people run into trouble is declaring `char *p = "some literal";` or `char buf[] = "some string";` and then attempt to return `p` or `buf` (which the function dutifully returns). The only problem is that memory for `"some literal"` or `"some string"` resides on the function *stack frame* which is *destroyed* when the function returns. So while the pointer address for both `p` and `buf` can properly be returned, what they pointed to was destroyed on return. That's the local declaration prob.